# GDAL and WMTS supprt

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, wmts

I have researching possibility to fetch raster file from WMTS server via GDAL. I have found some old post about that GDAL doesn't support WMTS (WMS only). However, I also find this information: http://gdal.org/frmt_wmts.html, where is mentioned that

> [...] Since GDAL 2.1, access to WMTS layers is possible with the GDAL WMTS client driver (needs Curl support). [...]

However I couldn't find any source of this GDAL 2.1, newest version on gdal.org is 2.0.

Can you tell my where can I find GDAL 2.1 or how to enable WMTS support for older version of GDAL? Now i use GDAL 1.11.2 on OS X.

Comment: 2.1.0 is not quite released. Perhaps you can test build from source?

Comment: if you have Windows you can get a copy from [GISinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php)

Comment: It may be possible to read from WMTS also with older GDAL if WMTS grids are simple https://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg23863.html.